# Some keys on the standard iOS keyboard render wrongly

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm working on an app where, on one of the views, a few of the keys turn black, and the alpha keys turn white (instead of being dark grey and grey respectively).

[image]
[image]

The pattern seems to be:

- call `becomeFirstResponder` on `viewWillAppear`
- present a modal view
- dismiss the modal view

I have tried calling `resignFirstResponder` on `viewWillDisappear`, but there is no change.

This is happening on both iOS 8 and 9, but only on iPhones. The iPad keyboard works as expected.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No. Though I believe there is a solution as an update to the app I was working on claims to have fixed it (after I left the company)